# Calculate average values over blocks of consecutive hourly records separated by gaps in time

Tags: python, excel, ms-access, sas, pivot-table

The data come to me in Excel. MS-Access is also available, of course. I also have SAS and Python.

I have data in two columns which I named `DateTime` and `Observation`. Observations are numeric and correspond to hourly readings. When sorted, there are runs of consecutive hourly observations over one or more days, separated logically (and irregularly) by gaps in time greater than one hour.

I need to automate the identification of the the time blocks (24,000 records) and calculate average, minimum, and maximum `Observation` for each discrete time block.

Comment: Do you have a preference on doing this in Excel vs Access? Like @pnuts said, look into Pivot Table. Have you made any attempt at least at the logic of how to attack the problem? Do you have a preference on whether your main data is sorted (assuming Excel and no pivot table) ?

Comment: How do you define a time block?

Comment: No preference on software to use. I can sort the DateTime field and observe where blocks of continuous hourly readings occur. The time blocks are defined by any break in hourly data (that is,  a skip of one or more hours - indicating the start of a new time block). This is easy to see in a spreadsheet or pivot, but how to automate select these irregular sized blocks and compute stats on them? In the pivot example, how to tag GP? 24,000 records.

Comment: "need to automate the identification of the the time blocks" Ok so how are these blocks identified? What logic should this automation utilize?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a PivotTable example:-

[image: SO29810103 example]